# html contains invalid utf-8 character(s) MPDF 6.0

Tags: php, utf-8, mpdf

possuo um texto em blob no banco de dados com a acentuação e tal..

quando passo ele pelo mpdf **SE** não for colocado `utf-8_encode` na variavel de leitura me retorna esse erro.

fiz a pergunta porque ja testei as outras respostas no stack e não resolveu...

aqui esta o código com a última tentativa de solução

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = true;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage','two');
$PDFContent = mb_convert_encoding($PDFContent, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($PDFContent);
ob_clean();
$mpdf->Output("./pdf_contratos/".$nome_c_pdf.".pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

O conteúdo do seu PDF está em uma codificação de caracteres incorreta.
A função `utf8_encode` faz uma conversão do ***charset*** do seu php para `UTF-8`.
Obviamente isso vai quebrar de servidor para servidor, pois a configuração vai estar diferente.

O correto no seu caso é utilizar a função `mb_convert_encoding`. Seu unico problema é que você está solicitando uma conversão de `UTF-8` para `UTF-8`.

Altere a seguinte linha:

```
$PDFContent = mb_convert_encoding($PDFContent, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Para:

```
$PDFContent = mb_convert_encoding($PDFContent, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

**Observação**: Estou considerando que o texto está codificado em `ISO-8858-1`, caso este não seja o seu caso, mude de acordo.